# Returning a Date from a Function Using sapply()

Tags: r

I am having an issue with dates in R.

I have some data with dates, however, the format is not consistent. Depending on the day of the month it is stored as dmmyyyy or ddmmyyyy. To fix this I wrote a small function (see below) which takes the string, checks the length, reformats and then returns a date. I use sapply(dates, formatDate) and according to my print outs everything works as expected. The resultant vector however does not contain the same values.

```
head(dates)
#> [1] 10651 11566 15493 13727 15920 15617
```

I am not sure what is happening here, any insights?

```
formatDate <- function(x){

  print(paste("Entering format date for ", x))

  if (nchar(x) == 8){

    print(paste("nchar = ", nchar(x)))

    day   <- substr(x, 1, 2)
    month <- substr(x, 3, 4)
    year  <- substr(x, 5, 8)

    print(paste("Day = ", day, " month = ", month, " year = ", year))

    x  <- paste(year,"-",month,"-",day, sep = "")

    print(paste("Date = ", x))

    x  <- as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

  } else if (nchar(x) == 7){

    day   <- substr(x, 1, 1)
    day   <- format(day, digits = 2)
    day   <- gsub(" ", 0, day)
    month <- substr(x, 2, 3)
    year  <- substr(x, 4, 7)

    x  <- paste(year,"-",month,"-",day, sep = "")
    x  <- as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

  } else {

    x <- NA

  }

  print(paste("Returning", x))
  flush.console()
  return(x)

 }
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting the numeric value.  To convert to Date, you can use `as.Date(yourreturnvector), origin='1970-01-01')` if I understand your question

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! I had tried returning as.Date(x), I didn't realise I could use it on the whole vector. One question - do I need to use the origin argument?

Comment: The reason is that `sapply` might change the `list` to matrix or so when the lengths are the same and the Date will be coerced to the numeric value it is stored.  It may be better to use `lapply` to avoid that

Comment: Yes, you need the `origin` argument

Comment: `simplify = FALSE` will also work to stop `sapply` for "collapsing" the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks way too complicated. If I understand correctly, you can simply do this:

```
x <- c("1072015", "11072015")
as.Date(formatC(as.integer(x), width = 8, flag = 0), format = "%d%m%Y")
#[1] "2015-07-01" "2015-07-11"
```

Comment: Thanks. The added complication is in the 1st-9th of the month where the format is dmmyyyy instead of ddmmyyyy. I could use your suggestion for the other dates. I guess I would have to add a 0 to the start of the other dates.

Comment: No, as this example shows clearly, you don't. `formatC` pads with zeros here.

Comment: I see now, sorry, this is perfect. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Although I like the out of the box thinking, it does not answer the question: Returning a Date from a Function Using sapply()

Answer (score 1):

Although Roland is right that this needed a completely different approach, I was actually looking for an answer to the question of the OP: returning a date from a function using `sapply()`.

Simple answer is: `sapply()` cannot return dates. But if you want to coerce dates using `sapply()`, you can use `as.Date()` with the right `origin` to return dates. Example dates and function:

```r
dates <- c("October 21 2012", "Sep 22 2019")

guess_date <- function(x) {
  # just for test purposes: try to coerce 2 different date formats
  if (is.na(as.Date(x, "%b %d %Y"))) {
    # format mmm dd yyyy
    return(as.Date(x, "%b %d %Y"))
  } else {
     # format mmmm dd yyyy
    return(as.Date(x, "%B %d %Y"))
  }
}
```

So `guess_date()` will always return a class `Date`. But now the check with `sapply()`:

```r
sapply(dates, guess_date)
#> October 21 2012     Sep 22 2019 
#>           15634           18161
```

And what you're looking for:

```r
as.Date(sapply(dates, guess_date), origin = "1970-01-01")
#> October 21 2012     Sep 22 2019 
#>    "2012-10-21"    "2019-09-22"
```